# Difference between MAP in Groovy and Java

Tags: java, groovy, collections

Currently, we are using Groovy as frontend and Java Spring as backend.

In groovy we define a property  `Map parameters = [:]` which will assign to `private Map<String, Object> parameters;` in Java.

I have a question regarding the instance of this MAP interfaces in both languages. As I read groovy create by default instance of `LinkedHashMap` and Java create by default instance of `HashMap` is it true?

My overall requirement is to preserve the order of data, which `LinkedHashMap` does but `HashMap` not.

So as frontend is already `LinkedHashMap`, it will pass ordered data into the backend.

```
public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}
```

Is it true?
Do I need to change model in JAVA (backend) from `Map` to `LinkedHashMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I read groovy create by default instance of LinkedHashMap and Java create by default instance of HashMap is it true?

Java, in fact, doesn't create any kind of map by default. The developer picks which `Map` implementation they instantiate (almost always). Java doesn't have a counterpart for Groovy's map literal `[:]`, so there's no "default" type to instantiate in Java. As for Groovy, it's true that the map literal creates a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
groovy:000> [:].getClass()
===> class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

> So as frontend is already LinkedHashMap, it will pass ordered data into the backend. [...] is it true?

Yes. During runtime, the `Map` object that's passed to `setParameters()` will be as generated by your "front-end" code. The call would simply behave the same way as though you'd created a `LinkedHashMap` from your Java code and passed it to the  method.
The runtime won't re-shape the object into a `HashMap` (even if it had to do something like that, making it a `HashMap` would be curiously arbitrary). All that matters here is that the types are compatible, and `LinkedHashMap` *is a* `Map`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is
an interface.  So if you demand a `Map` as argument or parameter, you
are only requesting those guarantees.

If you demand further guarantees (e.g. that LinkedHashMap preserve
insertion order), then you are better off requesting that explicitly.

Since you are talking "backend" and "frontend" there is also the matter
of transport between the two.  If you are using transports (and not
direct calls), that are no able to hold order in maps (e.g. JSON), then
you are better off to not rely on the different data types.  E.g. use
a list of key-value tuples instead.

#### Side note about the defaults

Groovy has a *literal* to quickly create maps (`[:]` or forms with keys
like `[a: 42]`).  Those maps are `LinkedHashMap` as you stated.

```
groovy:000> [:].getClass()
===> class java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

Since Java as of up to 15 has no literal for maps there is no "default"
-- the default is what you make it.

In general it's best to always think about the data type you are
actually in need of.  This also means, that the map literal of Groovy
can be the *wrong* choice.